# Google sheets - format a column by comparing values with another

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 2 columns, one has unique values the other one a list of several values;
I need to know if all the values of my first column are somewhere in the second one

Thank you

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | A, B, C |
| B | D, E, F |
| D | G,R, Y |

I tried with =COUNTIF(FILTER(B:B,A:A=ROW(A:A)),C:C) > 0
But I can't manage to write this formulae correctly

I expected the column A to be green if the value exists in column B

Answer (score 0):

With REGEXMATCH you'll be able to find the value in the next column. Try with:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B1,A1)*(A1<>"")
```

[image]

### OPTION 2

Above was to checking if it appears in the corresponding row. To check the entire column with more than one value per row:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN(",",1,B:B),A1)*(A1<>"")
```

[image]